# svn update を実行すると "SSL handshake failed: SSL disabled due to library version mismatch" エラーが発生する

Tags: ssl, svn, openssl

svn を update しようとしたら以下のエラーが発生するようになりました。
この解消方法を教えてもらえないでしょうか？

```
$ svn up
Updating '.':
svn: E175002: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'https://example.com/'
svn: E175002: OPTIONS (URL: 'https〜'): SSL handshake failed: SSL > disabled due to library version mismatch (https〜)
```

#### 環境

- subversion 1.7.7
- openssl 1.0.2
- Mac OS X 10.8.5

Comment: こちら [SVN: SSL disabled due to library version mismatch](http://nickveenhof.be/blog/svn-ssl-disabled-due-library-version-mismatch) が参考になるかもしれません。

Comment: > heliac2001
ご案内本当にありがとうございました。

Comment: @kitcon 本質問に関して解決出来たようですが、タイトルをクローズに変更するのではなく、解決策を自身で回答として記入して、チェックマークを付けて頂ければと思います。そうすると他の方にも参考になると思いますので。宜しくお願いします。

Comment: http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/1676/%E3%82%BF%E3%82%A4%E3%83%88%E3%83%AB%E3%81%AB-%E3%82%AF%E3%83%AD%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BA-%E3%81%A8%E5%90%AB%E3%81%BE%E3%82%8C%E3%81%9F%E8%B3%AA%E5%95%8F%E3%81%AE%E5%AF%BE%E5%87%A6

Comment: > tomute
ご案内ありがとうございます。了解しました。
ただ、チェックマークをつけたいのですが、どうも表示されないみたいです。Googleで調べたりして探してます。もうちょっと調べて、出てきたら点けます。

> natsu ki tinyak
問題にしてしまってすいません。。。もうちょっとヘルプ見たり、そちらの内容も目を通しておきます。

Comment: 教えていただいた情報に沿って、ターミナルから以下のコマンドを打つことで解決できました。
`$ sudo port upgrade neon`

Answer (score 1):

コメント欄で教えていただいた情報に沿って、ターミナルから以下のコマンドを打つことで解決できました。

参考にしたページ:
[SVN: SSL disabled due to library version mismatch](https://nickveenhof.be/blog/svn-ssl-disabled-due-library-version-mismatch)

```
$ sudo port upgrade neon
```

---

*この投稿は [@kitcon さんのコメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/6505/svn-update%e3%81%97%e3%82%88%e3%81%86%e3%81%a8%e3%81%99%e3%82%8b%e3%81%a8ssl-handshake-failed-ssl-disabled-due-to-library-version-misma#comment5711_6505) の内容を元に コミュニティwiki として投稿しました。*